# What is a "snippet"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Google says snippet is a small piece or brief extract.
"snippets of information about the war"

I would like to know if it is used for things and objects? Or some examples of its usage.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock you are right, I removed my second question, but those I address are something like `[edit]` in front of heading titles on any Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A snippet is indeed a small piece of information or news.

Here are some exemplary sentences:

- I heard snippets of conversation.
- The article gave a few snippets from her forthcoming memoirs.
- The guidebook is full of interesting snippets of information.
- A snippet of conversation.
- Brief snippets of interviews.
- Snippets of dialogue from the TV show.
- Vocal snippets in the background of the song.
- The radio programme featured a few snippets from the new album.

Comment: thank you, consider this link of Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning, you see some brackets including "edit" in front of headings. what are they called?

Comment: If you've been given an answer you deem valuable and correct, please accept it. That's how all StackExchange websites work and grow.

Comment: Sure, however it is also recommended to wait a while before accepting an answer and I usually do that after some days. Here I just asked another question, though maybe irrelevant, and I wait to see if one answer that too or not. (I upvoted your answer too)

Comment: [ edit ] It's simply a hyperlink. But [ 1 ], [ 2 ], ... are called references.

Comment: Michael, it's considered bad form to pester others for votes or acceptance. And @Ahmad is correct, it's [recommended to wait a bit before accepting](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer), even if yours is "perfect". Ahmad knows quite well how SE works, no need to remind him.

Comment: @KhanhTranDinh thanks I just thought they may have anything to snippet, but now I think the unrelated instructions ... in an article maybe counted snippet.

Comment: I'm sorry, I truly am. I'm quite active on other StackExchange sites and there I often see people asking this. I meant no offense nor pestering and I will be more patient in the future.